# Что такое handler в python?

Tags: python

Что такое handler в python? Вот обычный код начинается писать с букв а именно handler со символа '@', почему?

Comment: Это декоратор. Вот статейка: https://tproger.ru/translations/demystifying-decorators-in-python/

Comment: handler - это просто такое английское слово. Никакой такой особой конструкции в питоне нет. А с собачки в питоне обычно начинается использование вышеупомянутых декораторов, которые можно использовать много для чего, не только для handler'ов

Comment: Окей, спасибо:)

Comment: Под handler обычно подразумевается обработчик чего-то (каких-то событий, входящих соединений, сообщений и т.д.) Это не специфическое конкретно для Python понятие. Скорее всего в коде, где вы это увидели, через декоратор делают функцию обработчиком чего-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python `@` это особый знак который обозначает обернуть функции в другую или же по другому - использовать декоратор.

#### Теория

Ево можно использовать почти везде как дополнение, а `handler` это название функции которой обвернуть вашу функцию.
На самом деле лучший пример использования декораторов в создание телеграм ботов, они там на каждом носу.
Вы с помощью декораторов можете добавлять фишки разные например сделать так чтобы ваш декоратор измерял время исполнения функции или изменял аргументы

#### Практика

Щас покажу на самом простом деле

```py
def clocker(func):
    def clock(*args):
        import time
        start_time = time.time()
        func(*args)
        print(f"[{time.time() - start_time}]{{func.__name__}")
    return clock

@clocker
def main():
    for i in range(0,1000):
        print(i)
main()
```

Разберём этот код - первое что мы делаем это создаём свою функцию декоратор которая тоже имеет функцию, пайтон воспринимает так дать фукнции `clocker` саму функции и всё про ее, а функции `clock` ее аргументы.
Наш код идёт так, сначала идёт функция `clocker`, потом `clock` она уже запускает нашу функцию и в конце показывает имя функции с временем на выполнения

Comment: Я попытался максимально детально разобрать декоратор,  и попытаться "объяснить на пальцах" все их тонкости